# cUrl command C++ code replacement

Tags: c++, c, qt, curl, libcurl

I have this cUrl command that I need to execute in my C++ program under Linux, I am using Qt how and included libcUrl, I need to know the exact method call that is equavilant to this cUrl command:

```
curl -d 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=mdme2323&client_secret=asdaeqwedsa24124ewesiou&scope=http://api.microsofttranslator.com' https://datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/OAuth2-13 | python -m json.tool
```

Answer (score 1):

What about execute the command in a new process?

```
QString cmd("curl -d 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=mdme2323&client_secret=asdaeqwedsa24124ewesiou&scope=http://api.microsofttranslator.com' https://datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/OAuth2-13 | python -m json.tool");
QProcess::execute(cmd);
```

Comment: Then how to get its returned data?

Comment: BTW, in the stdout I got this "curl: option -m: expected a proper numerical parameter
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information" so can you the command didn't executed well.

Comment: I think you need add shell command before the curl. Since pipe is part of shell's feature.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I fixed it:

```
QProcess* proc = new QProcess();
QString cmd( "/bin/sh" );
QStringList args;
args << "-c" << "curl -d 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=islam123&client_secret=23ewsed323we2ewesiou&scope=http://api.microsofttranslator.com' https://datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/OAuth2-13";
proc->execute(cmd, args);
data = proc->readAll();
```